# Need to count number of times sequence of letters occurs in string R

Tags: string, r, search, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

So I have a sequence of nucleotides and I need to count the number of times the word gaga appears in the sequence.  This is what I have so far:

```
dna=c("a","g","c","t")
N=16
x=sample(dna,N,4)
x2=paste(x,collapse="")
x2
```

Here is an example output:

```
gtaggcctaattataa
```

Eventually, I am going to write a loop to make this run 100 times and plot a histogram of the counts of the word "gaga."  So, my main question is: How can I write a function or code to search through the string x2 and count the number of occurrences of the word "gaga."

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: how do overlaps count?  is "gagaga" 1 or 2? is "gagagaga" 2 or 3?  There are almost certainly some Bioconductor packages that can do this very efficiently.  Check out `matchPattern` from the `Biostrings` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
?regex
sapply( gregexpr( "gaga", c("gtaggcctaattataa", 
                            "gtaggcctaatgagaataa", 
                            "gagagaga") ) ,
        function(x) if( x[1]==-1 ){ 0 }else{ length(x) } )
[1] 0 1 2
```

Comment: OOOPS. Need to check for -1.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a wrapper for DWin's solution found in the qdap package:

```
x<- c("gtaggcctaattataa", "gtaggcctaatgagaataa", "gagagaga")

library(qdap)
qdap:::termco.h(x, "gaga", seq_along(x))

##   3 word.count term(gaga)
## 1 1          1          0
## 2 2          1          1
## 3 3          1          2
```

If you want just the counts:

```
qdap:::termco.h(x, "gaga", 1:3)[, 3]
```

Comment: Note this and DWin's method will not find overlaps as Ben points out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that counts overlaps too:

```
vec <- c("gagatttt",
"ttttgaga",
"gaga",
"tttgagattt",
"gagagaga",
"gagaga")


lengths(strsplit(vec, "ga(?=ga)", perl = TRUE)) - 1L
# [1] 1 1 1 1 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stri_count_fixed` from `stringi` package

```
    dna=c("a","g","c","t")
    N=160
    x=sample(dna,N,4)
    x2 <- stri_paste(x,collapse="")
    stri_count_fixed(x2,"gaga")
    ## 2
```